# 404 Page is generated instead of proper 301 redirect to new post

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I changed permalink from **/%postname%-%post_id%/** to **/%postname%/** only. But the problem is that I can't get any method to redirect 301 old permalink to new one.

I searched google and found [this plugin](http://scott.yang.id.au/code/permalink-redirect/) which redirect the old permalink to new one. When  I check the HTTP Response Header, it also shows the old page is being redirected to new one but actually in the content it shows 404 page. Here is [the example page](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://www.shoutpedia.com/ie9-has-just-been-released-here-are-direct-download-links-8344/&gzip=yes&http=1.1).

Even when I try to fetch the page in Google webmaster tools, the bot fails to fetch the old page.

Is there any way to fix the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way is just add some redirect into your .htaccess file, if you use Apache server.
You can easily populate the url list for your legacy links by write some sql query.

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN FIX URL
Redirect /my-sample-post-100 /my-sample-post/
Redirect /my-2nd-sample-post-101 /my-2nd-sample-post/
...
etc
# END FIX URL
```

Comment: My blog contains about 1000 posts. Can I write them all in the .htaccess??

Comment: Populate it by mysql query:

Comment: Yes, you can. Many sites has big .htaccess. It is much fast than the request kick to worpress itself. Make sure you add them at top of your .htaccess file.
SELECT CONCAT('Redirect /', post_name, '-',ID, '/ /', post_name, '/') FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_name != ''

Comment: Thank you. Can I select the posts from This.Date (09-12-2009 etc) to THAT.DATE (10-08-2012) according to published date?? Or if you could modify the above query so that it outputs the posts according to published date. Currently it populates according the modification date.

Comment: BTW don't I need to write 301 just after "Redirect"?

Comment: No, I do not think [Redirect] accept [301], otherwise, you are looking for [RewriteRule] - it is more complicated and slower.(Please read : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)
Here is the sql you looking for (date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'):
SELECT CONCAT('Redirect /', post_name, '-',ID, '/ /', post_name, '/') FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_name != '' AND post_date < '2012-10-08' ORDER BY post_date

Comment: I think it will work SELECT CONCAT('Redirect /', post_name, '-',ID, '/ /', post_name, '/') FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_name != '' AND post_date >= '2009-05-01' AND post_date <= '2012-05-15'

Comment: Finally I have deleted the plugin and using Redirect method. Till now everything is working fine.